# joomla module calls components model method

Tags: module, joomla3.1

What is the way to call components model method in a joomla module. I know there is a helper file inside of custom module and that should do the job, but how they do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you do it in the helper file or in the main file. The helper file is just a nice place to stuff away this kind of code :)

To call the model you need to include it first since it's not autoloaded. That means usually using something like `require_once('components/com_content/models/article')`.
After that you can instantiate the class with `$class = new ContentModelArticle` and call the method `$item = $class->getItem()`.
That should at least work in theory :)